# Is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$ a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am new to metric spaces, my approach would be since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is path connected, then $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected. Then since $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it should be path connected and hence connected as well. But i am not too sure and wish to hear out. Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb{Q} $is not connected

Comment: You seem to be using the implication "If a space is connected then every subspace is connected", or perhaps "If a space is path connected then every subspace is path connected". Counterexamples to either of those implications are easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It were so would $\pi_2[\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}] = \mathbb{Q}$ be. Quod non.

Or otherwise put (this was one direction of it):

$A \times B$ is connected iff both  $A$ and $B$ are connected.

Right to left is a classic theorem, for left to right we use images under projections.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be an irrational number.

$\mathbb{R} \times \big(\langle -\infty, x\rangle \cap \mathbb{Q}\big)$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \big(\langle x, \infty\rangle \cap \mathbb{Q}\big)$ are two nonempty disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$, whose union is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

They are also open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$:

$$\mathbb{R} \times \big(\langle -\infty, x\rangle \cap \mathbb{Q}\big) = \underbrace{\big(\mathbb{R} \times \langle -\infty, x\rangle\big)}_{\text{open in }\mathbb{R}^2} \cap \big( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}\big)$$
$$\mathbb{R} \times \big(\langle x, \infty\rangle \cap \mathbb{Q}\big) = \underbrace{\big(\mathbb{R} \times \langle x, \infty\rangle\big)}_{\text{open in }\mathbb{R}^2} \cap \big( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}\big)$$

Hence, $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected.